# createEffect causes continous loading when error occurred in angular

Tags: angular

When addPlacement api call is giving 409(conflict error) , the UI page goes on continuous loading.
I want to show an error "Conflict error occurred" and stop loading when api throws 409.

```
addPlacement$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PlacementActions.AddPlacement),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this._placementAPIClient.addPlacement(action.payload).pipe(
          switchMap(data => {
            console.log(action.payload);
            this._slotAPIClient.UpdateSlotsPostPlacement([{'firstName':action.payload.studentDetails.firstName.....}]).subscribe((res)=>{});
            return [PlacementActions.AddPlacementSuccess({ payload: data })];
          }),
          tap(() => {
            this._manifoldPanelService.closeAllManifoldPanels();
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            return of(PlacementActions.AddPlacementError(error));
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: I assume that some spinner/load animation is persisted, correct? If so, which action or line is supposed to stop it?

Comment: my browser is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NgRx effect requires you to dispatch the action. And it looks like your error handling fails to do so. This ends up in the situation you are describing. Try adding `filter` after `mergeMap` to filter all stream modifications that do not contain an action.

```
addPlacement$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PlacementActions.AddPlacement),
    mergeMap(action => { /* whole merge map magic */ }),
    filter(action => !!action)
  )
);
```